# Adding up values stored in Firebase and displaying total in a FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve a list of monthly expenses from Firebase, add up the amount of each monthly expense and show it in a FutureBuilder.
In the Text widget i'm simply getting null. Been trying to google an answer for the past half hour but i don't even know where to begin as in what to search for.

Tried throwing in some print statement to see whats going on but any print statement I put in after the provider call doesn't show.

EDIT: Added Future casts to the commented lines. still no luck. but ignored the variable and called the future function directly from the FutureBuilder. Now all print statements are working and it is returning an instance of 'MonthlyExpense'. It is null still.

```
class SummaryView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SummaryViewState createState() => _SummaryViewState();
}

class _SummaryViewState extends State<SummaryView> {
  

  /*  Removed future variable and initState()
  Future<double> _totalExpensesAmount; //Future<double> added

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("init");
    _totalExpensesAmount = _getTotalExpensesAmount();
  }
  */

  Future<double> _getTotalExpensesAmount() async { //Future<double> added
    print("started");
    final user = Provider.of<BPUser>(context);
    print("user: $user");
    double expensesTotal = 0.0;

    var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("BPUsers/${user.uid}/monthlyexpenses")
        .get();
    print(snapshot);
    List<MonthlyExpense> searchedProducts =
        DatabaseService().monthlyExpenseListFromSnapshot(snapshot);
    print(searchedProducts);
    for (var i = searchedProducts.length; i >= 1; i--) {
      expensesTotal += double.parse(searchedProducts[i].amount);
    }
    return Future<double>expensesTotal; //Future<double> added
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: mainBackgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _getTotalExpensesAmount(), // called the function directly
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Text(
                      "${snapshot.data}",
                      style: nameStyle,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text("Loading...");
                  }
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The monthlyExpenseListFromSnapshot function (which works perfectly in another widget I use it in):

```
List<MonthlyExpense> monthlyExpenseListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return MonthlyExpense(
          name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
          amount: doc.data()['amount'] ?? '',
          isActive: doc.data()['isActive']);
    }).toList();
  }
```

The firebase database:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue was to skip the variable and the init call and call the _getTotalExpensesAmount() future function (adding the Future signature to it).

Secondly my for loop was wrong. needed to change the conditions to:

```
for (var i = searchedProducts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Everything is working fine now!

Comment: great! Remember that you can mark your own answer as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're getExpensesTotal doesn't return a future.  Because of this, the widgetvwill never rebuild since the data is already calculated.  FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder only cause a rebuild AFTER data been loaded after the initial build.  Try surrounding your expensesTotal with Future.value.

Comment: I think i get what you mean, in  _getTotalExpensesAmount() the return doesn't await for the database calls? it returns with null instantly.
i changed the return statement with return Future<double>.value(expensesTotal);
but no luck

Comment: Let me take a look  at a previous project I did this in.  I can never remember the exact way to do this.  I'll have an answer to.orrow morning, as it's almost midnight here.

Comment: Good to hear! your should post your answer and mark it as answered, so other people can see find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the signature of the function to represent what it is expected, in this case `Future <double>`.

```dart
// ....
Future<double> _getTotalExpensesAmount() async {
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this along with adding Future<double>.value() on the return and still it kept returning null :/

Comment: I think that the issue is due to the definition of the variable `_totalExpensesAmount`. Please add the correct signature `Future<double>` or make a cast.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the function instead of a variable, this will be more readeable. `future: _getTotalExpensesAmount(),`

Comment: Calling the function instead of the variable just possibly fixed it i believe! 
I've edited the post to show the updated code and now all the print statements work. It is returning an instance of 'MonthlyExpense'. Although its still displaying null but atleast i think i know where to go from here.

So the take away is that it doesn't like if you create a Future variable, then assign a function to that variable in the init()?